# Weighted, Undirected Adjacency List: Maximum Weighted Edge in a Single Cycle in O(n)

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

So this problem involves an AdjacencyList based graph G. This graph has exactly n edges and n vertices. It also has one, and only one cycle. What is the fastest possible algorithm (as far as big O notation) to find the edge with the maximum weight in the cycle?

I'm pretty sure this can be done in O(n), but I'm struggling to figure out the specifics, considering that you must verify that your result is in a cycle. The original way I thought through this problem was a simple depth first search, which you could use to find the maximum weighted edge in the entire graph in O(n) time (since V+E = 2n). You could then do another search to verify whether or not this edge was in the cycle. If it is, then you have your answer in O(n), but if it is not it will take O(n^2) time. This is definitely not ideal though and I'm looking for an O(n) solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return in the DFS which node was found in the cycle, then go back marking every node up in the DFS tree as part of the cycle (until the found node itself). Something like this:

```
DFS(v):
    mark v as visited
    for edges (v, w) in E:
        if w is not visited:
             last_node = DFS(w)
             if last_node != -1:
                  test (v, w) as maximum edge
                  if last_node != v:
                      return last_node
                  else:
                      return -1       
        else:
             test (v, w) as maximum edge
             return w  
    return -1
```

Comment: Is this O(n) though? Since your doing a DFS within a for loop, this would be at least O(nlog(n)) I think.

Comment: This is O(n). You never visit a node more than once or edge more than twice. Actually, this is just a regular DFS with a return value (and some checks over it).

Comment: So that call of DFS(w) isn't another Depth First Search? How do you know that that will run in O(1)?

Comment: Also what is test(v, w)?

Comment: I assumed you understood how a DFS worked, when you asked the question. The recursive DFS call is no different from the classic implementation, [it's in the wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode). And it is largely proved to be O(|V|+|E|) = O(n), in your case.

Comment: And `test (v, w) as maximum edge` is a placeholder for you to put your logic to verify if the weight of the edge (v, w) is greater than the maximum already seen.